# gradlew installdebug not installing apk on device. what to do?

Tags: android, debugging, gradlew

I run my android apps using USB cable and gradlew installdebug code on cmd. It was working till morning. But now my application is not installing in my device. they show componentname=table. What is that? What to do? is there any other trick to run apk on a device using debugging?

Comment: have you tried ````Revoke USB debugging authorizations```` from the developer options and trying again ?

Comment: yes, bro, it doesn't work

Comment: damn, goodluck, let me know what you eventually do to get it working

Comment: nothing bro. I started using genymotion

Comment: if you were having android emulator problems, try making a new one ?